# What code to use to distinguish values in imacros?

Tags: imacros

I am trying to take only the value within, not disabled one below.Trying to take `44`.

How to write code in imacros ?

```
< span class="productOption 94255 disabled" attributeoptionid="2">42< /span >

< span class="productOption 94255" attributeoptionid="28">44< /span >
```

Comment: TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=********    EXTRACT=TXT

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the number after "productionOption" is always the same, I believe that

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:productionOption<SP>94255 EXTRACT=TXT
```

would work.

The "disabled" span element is only tagged if you use either a wildcard (*), or include " disabled" in the TAG attribute parameter.